# Issue with reading partial header CSV using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file using pandas.read_csv when the files header is not full, i.e., only some columns have names, others are empty.
When reading the data frame using .iloc I only get the columns which the header do not have any names.
The reason some columns do not have names is that the column size is variable and I did not assign a name for each column.

here's an example of the code, input file and output

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('filename.csv', sep = ",", header = 0)
dataframe = dataframe.iloc[::]
dataset = dataframe.values[:,0:]
```

**input file**

```
A B C           
3 5 0      1    2   3

3   5   4      5    6   7

3   5   8      9    10  11

3   5   12     13   14  15
```

**dataset output**

```
dataset = [[1,2,3][5,6,7][9,10,11][13,14,15]]
```

How can I get dataframe to use the entire array (without the header)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `.values` to get back numpy ndarray.

```
from io import StringIO

csv_file = StringIO("""A B C
3 5 0 1 2 3
3 5 4 5 6 7
3 5 8 9 10 11
3 5 12 13 14 15""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,sep='\s',engine='python')
df.values
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [13, 14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not **skip=1** when you load the csv file ?

Comment: Thanks, it did the work, small comment is that on my revision the excat parameter is skiprows=1

Comment: @Amir opps ! sorry my bad